# While Loop won't terminate?

Tags: java, do-while

I'm using a while loop and it won't terminate when it should. If it was working correctly, then it would terminate when `randno` was either `== highbound` or `== lowbound`.

Code of the loop:

```
do {
    do {
        randno = (int) (Math.round((Math.random()*(4)) + 0.5)-1);
        direction = getDirection(randno,heading);      
    } while (robot.look(direction)==IRobot.WALL);
    System.out.println(randno);
    System.out.println(highbound);
    System.out.println(lowbound);
    System.out.println("---------------");
} while (randno!=lowbound | randno!=highbound);
```

The output is either `3 3 2 ------`, or `2 3 2 ------`, so the loop should end. The first loop ends properly (I embedded them to try and get it to work...). What is going wrong?

Comment: it's a `while` loop, not an `until` loop, so it has to be different from lowbound *and* highbound to continue with the loop, not *or*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`randno!=lowbound | randno!=highbound` is always true, since `randno` can't be equal to both `lowbound` and `highbound` (assuming they are not equal).

Therefore the loop never terminates.

If you wish to terminate when `randno` is different than both bounds, change your condition to :

```
while (randno==lowbound || randno==highbound)
```

If you wish to terminate when `randno` is the same as one of the bounds, change your condition to :

```
while (randno!=lowbound && randno!=highbound)
```

EDIT : based on your question, you want the second option.

Comment: Hey,thank you so much! I know it was probably a stupid question but I've literally been staring at it for hours...